# TypeError: Input() missing 1 required keyword-only argument

Tags: python, массивы

В массиве A найти разность сумм элементов с чётными и нечётными индексами. Элементы массива: aі (a итое) = i!

```
n = int(input("Enter n: "))
a = []

def factorial(i):
  if (i == 0): return 1
  elif(i == 1): return 1
  return i*factorial(i-1)

def Input(*a, n):
  for i in range(0, n): 
    a[i] = factorial(i)

def Output(*a, n):
  for i in range(0, n):
    print(a[i], " ")
  print("\n")

print("Array A:")
Input(a, n)
Output(a, n)
D = 0
N = 0
def Summa(D, N):
  for i in range(n):
    if (i % 2 == 0): D += a[i]
    elif(i % 2 != 0): N += a[i]
Summa(D, N)
S = D - N
print("Subtraction:", S)
```

Ошибка:
line 19, in 
Input(a, n)
TypeError: Input() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'n'.
Не понимаю, как решить эту проблему

Comment: А что означают звёздочки перед аргументом a, для чего они нужны?

Comment: Для передачи всех элементов массива

Comment: а без звёздочки они не передадутся?

Comment: По сути, тоже передадутся

Answer (score 0, accepted):

по идее ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```
n = int(input("Enter n: "))

def factorial(i):
    return 1 if i < 2 else i * factorial(i - 1)

def Input(n):
    return [factorial(i) for i in range(n)]

def Output(a, n):
    print(*a, "\n", sep=" ")

print("Array A:")
a = Input(n)
Output(a, n)

def Summa():
    D = 0
    N = 0

    for i in range(n):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            D += a[i]
        else:
            N += a[i]

    return (D, N)

D, N = Summa()
S = D - N
print("Subtraction:", S)
```

Ошибки у вас:

1. так массив не заполнить

   ```
    for i in range(0, n): 
        a[i] = factorial(i)
   ```

ведь вы объявили массив как `a = []`, т.е. элементов в нем нет, поэтому вы и обращаться к ним не можете, минимум вы должны были бы сделать так:

```
    for i in range(0, n): 
        a.append(factorial(i))
```

2. для передачи параметров в функцию достаточно было бы использовать обычный массив

вы использовали конструкцию

```
def Input(*a, n):
```

это ошибка, кроме того вы все равно не можете заполнить глобальную переменную `a` из функции в таком виде

3. опять же работа с локальными переменными, когда нужны глобальные

в таком коде

```
def Summa(D, N):
  for i in range(n):
    if (i % 2 == 0): D += a[i]
    elif(i % 2 != 0): N += a[i]
```

вы работаете с локальными переменными не изменяя глобальных, т.е. вы получать 0 будете всегда для вашего код

4. не ошибка, а просто неаккуратность - есть у вас условие бинарное (четное или нечетное), то зачем нужно `elif` и вторая проверка?

у вас

```
if (i % 2 == 0): D += a[i]
elif(i % 2 != 0): N += a[i]
```

но это избыточно и достаточно

```
if i % 2 == 0: D += a[i]
else: N += a[i]
```